# AngularJS error when added as script

Tags: angularjs

I just added those srcipt to my web page and has en error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.js"></script>
```

This is exact my example and it works on Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/frbrn32d/2/

```
junk after document element main.html:6
DOMException [NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: "Access to restricted URI denied"
code: 1012
nsresult: 0x805303f4
location: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.js:9032]
```

Comment: Frontend package managers like Bower, combined with a task runner like Grunt or Gulp would take care of downloading + concatenating vendor scripts for you. Does this error still occur when you switch the position of the `<script>` tags?

Comment: Yes, I tried different ways.

Comment: AngularJS and JQuery are two different libraries and not necessarily dependant. If you want to use jQuery with Angular, you need to insert the jQeury script before the AngularJS by the way. Can you share you .js file so we can take a look at what you are doing?

Comment: I there a way to downlad ALL ANGULAR js libs, in one ZIP file and add them in my project.

Comment: For example I need rangluar-route. Which version of anuglar do I need to use (1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0) do be happy wiht angular-route.js?

Comment: Go to https://code.angularjs.org/ and get whichever version you want

Comment: Is there a way to handle those problems? Or this is not a problems?

Comment: you can get all the compatible modules for 1.2.9 for example from https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/. You can then download and manage them as you wish. But as @TomA said, using a package manager like Bower[http://bower.io/] or npm[https://www.npmjs.org/] would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61371/discussion-between-cmr-and-user1315599).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your fiddle. I made a change and it seems to be working. 
You had a typo there. It should be `alert not alerT.`

http://jsfiddle.net/1mjgf4u8/3/

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works fine on fiddle, but did not work when I create the same on my desktop. I updated exception in subject.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the files and inserting them locally in your page? Does that work?